# Detect country name for dropdown using IP address in Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, selenium, ip, webdriver

I just started using Selenium WebDriver (Java) to automate an e-commerce portal.

There is a dropdown in home page with all country names.  Based on the IP address, country name should be selected automatically.

How to detect country name for dropdown using IP address in Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: You should have test data available, that way there is no work to do in relating an IP to a country. You should have control and understand the data inside your environment, so stick dummy data in.

Answer (score 1):

Use a geolocator such as the one found at http://www.geobytes.com/iplocator.htm to get the country name based on the IP address.

Then, find the same value in your dropdown list and add the attribute "selected" to it.

Example if value returned is "United Kingdom":

```
<select name="country'>
    <input value="United States">
    <input value="United Kingdom" selected>
</select>
```

Do bear in mind that the list of countries or country names might vary, so try to stick to a standardized list of names.

Unfortunately I can't provide you with one. I have implemented a similar solution recently and found it to be a huge challenge to acquire a standard list of country names.